# CoreFoundation UTF-16 un-paired surrogate

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16, core-foundation

I'm trying to encode from utf16 to say utf32 using Apple Core Foundation API :

```
cfString = CFStringCreateWithBytes(nullptr, str, strLen, kCFStringEncodingUTF16, FALSE);

auto range = CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLenth(cfString));

CFStringGetBytes(cfString, range, kCFStringEncodingUTF32, 0, false, buffer, bufferSize, usedsize);
```

Most of the time that works, untill input buffer contains first part of surrogate pair say U+df9f, Corefoundation will simply return output without ill-formed characters.

So to be a bit unicode compliant, I have to manually determine that situation and follow unicode documentation to create standard substitution for that in form of U+FFFD:  http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch03.pdf

Same situation for  other encodings: like symbol 0x80 in the middle of utf-8, then CFStringCreateWithBytes always return nullptr instead of pointing to invalid character.

Is that expected behaviour or UB of Corefoundation, or may be there is a hint to tune CF to be reporting malformed input somehow?

UPDATE:

I did exactly following:

```
UInt8 str[] = {0x41, 0x00, 0x9f, 0xdf}; // coresponding to unicode A + invalid surogate pair

CFStringRef mystr = CFStringCreateWithBytes(nullptr, str, 4, kCFStringEncodingUTF16, false, FALSE);
```

after that mystr has 2 characters len according to CFStringGetLength(), so looks invalid char gets processed

```
std::vector<char> str(7);
CFStringGetCString(mystr, &*str.begin(), str.size(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

that gives me false, so no conversion to utf8 is possible, and Xcode debug watches shows nothing for string myStr.
So output is nothing for utf8, and c-string, ok after that i checked with conversion to utf-32 with get bytes routine

```
result = CFStringGetBytes(s, range, kCFStringEncodingUTF32BE, 0, false, buffer,  bufferSize, usedSize);
```

that gives me `usedSize=4`, `result=1`, and output contains `0x0041`, so only A symbol converted. So that is why i’m thinking no substitution happened for malformed surogate pair.

Comment: So, you are saying that when input UTF-16 data contains incomplete surrogates, or input UTF-8 data contains illegal bytes, `CFStringCreateWithBytes()` is not replacing them with codepoint U+FFFD automatically? `CFStringGetBytes()` is documented as being able to handle invalid codepoints when converting to bytes, but `CFStringCreateWithBytes()` is not handling when converting from bytes?  Hmm, sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: CoreFoundation is assuming that when you tell it your input is `kCFStringEncodingUTF16`, that it actually is. If your input contains un-paired surrogates, it is not valid UTF-16. CoreFoundation provides few guarantees if you give it improper data (and unfortunately, no methods for checking...).